# Irrationality of the Riemann zeta-function on odd arguments

Tags: irrational-numbers, riemann-zeta, conjectures

It is proved that infinitly many of the numbers $\zeta(2n+1)$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Is there a conjecture such as 'the numbers $\zeta(2n+1)$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$'?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, there is such a conjecture. This would be a consequence of Grothendieck's period conjecture (which actually imply the algebraic independence of the values $\zeta(2n+1)$). See for instance _GALOIS THEORY, MOTIVES AND TRANSCENDENTAL NUMBERS_ by Yves André.

Comment: Welcome to M.SE. You can upvote and accept suitable answers you get to your questions. Thank you!

Comment: The §5.7 of Yves André's paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.2569v1.pdf) states : "Grothendieck’s conjecture for this type of motives would imply that π and ζ(3), ζ(5), … are algebrically independent […]".

Answer (score 1):

If infinitely many $\zeta(2n+1)$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$, you can conclude that infinitely many are irrational.

Because if $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$, then

$$\forall (r,r')\in\mathbb Q^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}, \quad rx+r'y\ne 0,$$

so $x$ or $y$ is irrational, because if they were both rational, $r=y$ and $r'=-x$ would work.

And yes, there is such a conjecture, widely open so far.

(Because requested in the comments, [this paper](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~rivoal/articles/quaddefi.pdf) shows that infinitely many of the $\zeta(2n+1)$ are irrational.)

Comment: @user368031 For the references read his comment above because mine are all in french.

Comment: I edited to add a reference.